# Double value from dictionary differs very much

Tags: c#, dictionary, mono, key, double

When I get value of type double from dictionary I get very weird results - 30,75 instead of 12 or 31.** instead of 7. Full Controller code (method is **public async Task PayPal(int coins)**):

```
namespace *.Controllers
{
    public class BuyCoinsController : BaseController
    {

        private static Dictionary<int, double> PRICES = new Dictionary<int, double>
        {
            {10, 7.00},
            {20, 12.00},
            {50, 30.00},
            {100, 50.00}
        };

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ViewResult> PayPal(int coins)
        {
            try
            {
                double price = PRICES[coins]; // <=========================== here
            }
            ...
        }
```

I use `PRICES` dictionary only in this try-block. It's only reference to that object. It's driving me crazy...

Comment: Error may be away. Could you show us more of your code ?

Comment: could you please post all your code? Thanks

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - `Search completed - 2 matches.` - no other references.

Comment: Although that will not solve your problem, do yourself a favor and NEVER EVER use floating point variables for currency values. Use decimal or some other appropriate type, but please no floating point.

Comment: Thanks for down votes and close votes. @Olivier Jacot-Descombes saved honour of this community.

Comment: Daniel No @Olivier Jacot-Descombes' answer can not have solved the problem. Your question is not reproducible.

Comment: Mono + MonoDevelop + 2 references to dictionary. Yep, it's not reproducible indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable "lives" only in the code block it is declared. If you try to access `price` outside of the `try` block, you most probaly are accessing a variable declared elsewhere.

Declare the variable before the `try` block and also make sure to assign `price` a value in case of an exception.

```
double price;
try
{
    int coins = 20;
    price = PRICES[coins];
} catch {
    price = 0;
}
// Now price is "visible" here.
```

But I would suggest you to use `TryGetValue` instead, an thus avoid an exception in case the key is not found:

```
double price;
if (PRICES.TryGetValue(20, out price)) {
    Console.WriteLine("The price is {0}", price);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no price found!");
}
```

Comment: I'm checking this in debugger and when dictionary expands in MonoDevelop it says values and keys good, but price gets wrong value. I'll try your suggestion in moment and give feedback.

Comment: Are you shure, that you don't have a field or property or another variable `price` declared elsewhere and that you are not confusing the two? Right click on the faulty `price` variable and choose `Go To Definition` in the shortcut menu (right click).